# crush in something -- meaning?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Usage example with [a context](http://www.businessinsider.com/why-putin-will-lose-2015-1):

> It's easy to fantasize about Putin "saving" Europe from itself when you're in Germany or Greece, or better yet France. Such illusions are rare in Poland, Romania, the Baltic States, much less Ukraine, where the hungry Russian bear looms close-by. One wonders what Marine Le Pen would think of her **crush in** the Kremlin if France were located a thousand kilometers eastward of where it is.

What does that expression actually mean?

Comment: My guess is the writer is implying that Marine Le Pen is enamored with Vladimir Putin. So the writer of this piece believes that she "has a crush" ON Putin. Putin then would be "her crush" in the Kremlin. Probably a bit of hyperbole—she probably had  written favorably of Putin. Look up her writing to see what this piece refers to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One wonders what Marine Le Pen would think of her **crush** in the Kremlin if France were located a thousand kilometers eastward of where it is.

**Crush** here means "the person she *has a crush on*", that is, Vladimir Putin, who resides **in the Kremlin**.

See the Oxford Dictionary's entry on **[crush](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/crush)**:

> A person with whom someone is infatuated:
>   *it turns out she thought you were flirting with her **crush***

Of course this doesn't mean she really is infatuated with Putin; this is just the way the writer tries to express her current political strategy. She could be just using the Kremlin to gain more popularity at home.